# Prove that there is only one homotopy class of continuous functions from $X$ to $D$

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Question:

> Show that if $X$ is a topological space, and $D$ is the disk in the plane, then there is only one homotopy class of continuous functions from $X$ to $D$.

Answer: Only one case I know that if $f$ is a curve on the $D$ then it is homotopic to the center of the $D$, because the disk is path connected. I don't know how to prove in general and I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $f: X \to D$, the homotopy

$$F : X\times I \to D, F(x, t) = tf(x)$$

connects $f$ to the constant map.

Comment: So that way, what is the reason of "the disk"? Any space with origin can also will result in only one homotopy class of continuous functions. Am I right? Thank you.

Comment: If by "any space with origin" you mean that that space can be contracted to a point, then yes. @L.G.

Comment: Sorry, your suggestion in the answer works for $D - {\{\alpha}\}$ ($\alpha$ is not the origin) but $D - {\{\alpha}\}$ cannot be contracted to a point, say the origin (?) Thank you.

Comment: My answer does not work for $D -\{\alpha\}$ for any $\alpha$. (The $F$ might not be well defined). And $D - \{\alpha\}$ is not contractible. @L.G.